# Can I schedule machine boot via Dell iDRAC?

Tags: powershell, dell, dell-poweredge, scheduled-task, drac

I have a Dell PowerEdge R410 with iDRAC 6 configured and accessible.

I know we'll be losing power at some point this weekend and I have a time that I would like to power on the machine again.

From the iDRAC GUI, can I schedule a boot up time, or would I have to use an combination of ssh script + the racadm commands from another machine to pull that off?

I've been looking around but I can't seem to find anything for it in the iDRAC GUI, which makes me think it may not be possible there.

Another possibility: does the iDRAC MAC respond well to WOL requests? If so, I could maybe have a powershell script run the Start-Computer command to send the WOL magic packets to the iDRAC? Not sure if this is a workable/best method.

### Clarifications

- In short, my goal is to bring this server up at a specified date/time.
- The tools that I have at my disposal are:

  - Maybe a linux box in a failover building that could SSH in (not sure I'll have access to it)
  - My Win7 desktop (which may not be up)
  - I am familiar with PowerShell Scripting
  - I am minimally familiar with ssh (I understand it enough for basic tasks but have never had to automate it)
  - The iDRAC controller on the machine, which will presumably be up as soon as power returns.
  - anything available via the R410 BIOS (not sure if there is something like this)
- I know the DRAC doesn't power management -- I'm looking for a way to possibly use it to start up the machine (having a scheduled boot option in an iDRAC seems like it would naturally be a good fit, but I guess not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, iDRAC has no WOL, there is however a WOL on other network interfaces, but I wouldn't enable it if your machine is connected to the internet. I also doubt that iDRAC supports scheduled reboot. You idea to use an SSH script is seemingly the best way to go.

Comment: This does appear to be the case. I found an internal cloud datacenter to throw a management VM on and am using an SSH script on this to remote into the idrac and use racadm to send a powerup command to the server. It's working perfectly manually; working on the scheduled task aspect of it now. Thanks for the straightforward answer! This did end up being the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned WOL Magic Packets, but you also mentioned you have SSH at your disposal. Here's a way to power on a Dell with iDRAC using SSH:

​http://www.bartsp34ks.nl/networking/how-turn-on-your-dell-server-with-a-script-using-idrac-and-putty/

Establish an SSH session (the example had the command in a script file):

```
putty.exe -ssh admin@10.0.0.99 -m C:\putty\PowerOn.sh
```

Once the SSH session is established, run this command:

```
racadm serveraction powerup
```

Answer (score 1):

If power is cut hard in your environment, the UPS and your systems should return to their last power state... E.g. your servers should come up when power is restored... Unless you're talking about powering them off manually ahead of the power cut... but at that point (and if you know that timing), you should be able to schedule the power up again.

As for out-of-band management like the DRAC or HP's ILO, they are active on AC. There's no need for wake-on-LAN.

Comment: I should clarify: Not worried about OOB on the DRAC -- looking to use the DRAC connection to power up the box itself in a scheduled manner. We are powering them off ahead of time and I do know when I want them to come up, but I won't be there, hence trying to schedule them to come up in the easiest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have setup WOL on the R410 / IDRAC6 servers for similar reasons. 
The WOL is activated via a powershell script which wakes the servers in a very specific order as we have clusters and servers which depend on other systems being available first. 
While unable to schedule a power up on individual servers I accomplish this by having a Locally connected workstation with this ability which in turn can then run the WOL powershell script to manage the power up and monitor progess of service / node startup.
WOL was configured on one the system NICs on each server and the MAC address recorded in a hosts file with the server ID. This was done through the BIOS NIC menus.
The powershell script also logs progress and emails updates.
While in ideal conditions all runs well I have come across enough issues which have led me to insisting on being on site, some of these issues included elcectricians not completing work on time (late or partial power up) and system faults which only became visible following system power down and power up. The automated power up is still very valuable though as it reduces to risk of failure from human error - a possible issue at 3AM!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It may be simple as setting a cronjob from another Linux box.
Use the remote IPMI features of modern servers (iDRAC is complaint in that) and send the power on command:

`ipmipower --on -h hostname/oripaddressofidrac -u root -p password`

Comment: It's not possible to create schedules directly from the iDRAC GUI, but the iDRAC is a mini linux system, I think some hacking might get you something that could work, but that some advanced stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts-

1. You don't need to WOL an iDRAC - it's up as long as you have a working power cord and network cable. It doesn't need to be turned on - it's always on.
2. I don't know of any scheduling for power, so it would have to be done via script job from another machine
3. How is that machine (the one running the script) going to be turned on, if you lost power? Chicken and egg, I'm thinking
4. Actual solution 1 : when power is resumed, connect remotely to your network, SSH or browse to the DRAC, and manually power up the server. The DRAC will be awake if your power and LAN are working, remember.
5. Actual solution 2a and 2b : assuming you do have a working machine on the inside to run scheduled scripts, you could either run an SSH script against the DRAC to power up the server, or to send a WOL packet to the server itself, assuming it is configured to respond to these.

Comment: thanks for the response. 1) I'm referring to turning the machine on via an idrac which will come up automatically when the machine regains power. 2) thanks, i'll probably have to script it 3) we have many buildings/datacenters; only one is going down 4) I know how to do it manually, I'm looking to script it so I don't have to get up at 3am :) 4) that's the direction I'm going I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Connecting with WSMan you can connect to the iDRAC of the server(s) and get their powerstate. This then can then determine if you need to poweron the box or leave it as is. PowerShell can help with making this connection but you need to know the commands. The WOL dosn't apply being that it is an Out-of-Band Management device the iDRAC as it is always on as long as the server has power. I hate pointing to resources on other sites but in this case Dell has put together a doc to help with something close to what you are talking about. It uses PowerShell v3 to accomplish the task. http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-20-18-70-55/Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-Cim-Cmdlets-with-Dell-iDRAC.pdf

I hope this helps. We use iDRAC accross our 5k servers with much success.